# WebSocket. Ошибка при создании подключения

Tags: javascript, websocket

У меня есть веб приложение - video chat. Работает при помощи WebSockets. Хочу я его запустить на локальном сервере. Запускается на Tomcat. 
Когда запускаю, страница грузиться и вроде все работает, но в консоли вот такая ошибка:

WebSocket connection to 'ws://http//localhost:8080/nextrtc-example-videochat' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

подскажите, что это может быть и как это решить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очевидно, `ws://localhost:8080/`, а не `ws://http//localhost:8080/`

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> ws://http//localhost:8080/nextrtc-example-videochat
> ```

```
ws://localhost:8080/nextrtc-example-videochat
```

Comment: Помогите плз мне с моим вопросом по вебсекетам - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512116/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-websocket

Comment: @gilo1212, ничего не знаю.