# Как можно определить почему не работает связь с сервером (WebSocket)?

Tags: php, websocket

**Part 1**

---

**Как можно определить почему не работает связь с сервером?**

**Web-server: OpenServer**

Алиас - `localhost   ---- yii333.com`

Вообще по разному пробовал, и без алиаса.

Включал/выключал - `защитить сервер от внешнего доступа`

---

---

**Фаервол**: выключен

---

---

**Используемая библиотека websocket:** socketo.me

---

---

**Проверка включение websockets на веб-сервере**: Всё отрабатывает на отлично!

```
<?
  if(extension_loaded('sockets')) echo "Всё отрабатывает на отлично!";
  else echo "Не работает";
?>
```

phpinfo();

```
Registered Stream Socket Transports tcp, udp, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls, tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2
```

---

---

**Делаю по справочнику:**
http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world

тестирую связь:

> Running It ¶ Complete, let's run it and test it. Open up three
>   terminal windows, typing:
>
> $ php bin/chat-server.php $ telnet localhost 8080 $ telnet localhost
>   8080 In each of the telnet windows, type a message ("Hello World!")
>   and see it appear in the other!

**всё отлично работает**, связь есть, сообщения пересылаются.

Когда перехожу к следующему шагу **Next Steps**

> Next Steps ¶ Now that we have a basic working Chat application, let's
>   make that work in a web browser (Chrome, FireFox, or Safari [for
>   now]). First, let's go back to our chat-server.php script. We're going
>   to utilize another component of Ratchet; the WsServer class:
>
> ```
> require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
>
> $server = IoServer::factory(
>     new HttpServer(
>         new WsServer(
>             new Chat()
>         )
>     ),
>     8080
> );
>
> $server->run(); Run the shell script again, open a couple web browser windows, and open a javascript console or a page with the
> ```
>
> following javascript:
>
> var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080'); conn.onopen =
>   function(e) {
>       console.log("Connection established!"); };
>
> conn.onmessage = function(e) {
>       console.log(e.data); };

Вылетают ошибки

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/' failed: Error during
>   WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

этот код я отправлял как через консоль браузера, так и через html страничку. Перед тем как отправлять **js** код, я запускаю сервер через консоль, запущенную от **имени администратора** `php bin/chat-server.php`

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
conn.onopen = function(e) {
    console.log("Connection established!");
};

conn.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
};
```

Так-же, показывает что ошибка произошла в этой строке JS скрипта, если запускать скрипт через html страницу :

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
```

---

---

Если в адресной строке браузера набрать localhost:8080
то выдает ошибку:

```
400 (Bad Request)
```

---

---

Если в адресной строке браузера набрать localhost6:8080 или другой какой-нибудь адрес сервера, или выключить сервер, то выдаёт ошибку:

```
//если  выключить
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
//если ввести любое другое имя хоста
net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

---

[Очень похожая проблема, или такая-же](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/494566/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-websocket-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5?rq=1)

---

---

---

**Part 2**

---

Связь удалось настроить между сервером и клиентом.

```
   var conn = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8080');
        conn.onopen = function(e) {
        console.log("Connection established!");
    };

    conn.onmessage = function(e) {
        console.log(e.data);
    };
```

Но, связь с сервером нестабильна. Если мы первый раз попытаемся соединиться через JS скрипт, то получим **ошибку 400**. Если мы будет обновлять страницу, тем самым перезагружая  js скрипт, то примерно с второго/пятнадцатого раза, произойдёт связь с сервером. На сервере в консоли, отобразится лог о том что создан новый коннект. 
При отправки сообщения на сервер, поведение не менее странное. Мы можем отправить сообщение и сервер его прочитает и отобразит в консоли, а может и вообще не прочитать и ничего не отобразить в консоли. Причину всего этого, пока не удалось выяснить.

**Примечание:**
Если мы попробуем соединиться с эхо сервером `echo.websocket.org`, то соеденение будет стабильное и происходит с первого раза.

```
 var conn = new WebSocket('ws:echo.websocket.org');
            conn.onopen = function(e) {
            console.log("Connection established!");
        };

        conn.onmessage = function(e) {
            console.log(e.data);
        };
```

Comment: По ссылке другая проблема. Вам сервер хотя бы отвечает, не 101 а 400, но это уже сигнал, что сервер как минимум знаком с HTTP.

Comment: @D-side Мне кажется это из-за опенсервера, из-за того что там не как в денвере. Там свое окружение. Одна папка и много доменов. Хотя я  и на хостинге чуть-чуть проверял, не заработало ,может потому что немного времени уделил, что-то пропустил. очень сильно кажется что из-за опенсервера. Пока к сожалению проверить не смогу.

Comment: Без бутылки тут не разберешься пожалуй)) А, возможно, и без целой папки с проектом

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский  У меня почти получилось это сделать. Покрайней мере, связь с сервером уже  происходит. На сервере при запросе соеденения, происходит рукопожание, и сервер регистрирует новое соеденение (он начал писать это в логах, как идолжен был эттоделать) Проблема осталась, связанная с нестабилной связью, и, нету эхо ответа. То, есть, при запросе дать нам эхо, сервер ничего не дает, а потом, если будем еще просить эхо у него, он нас выбросит, и произойдет дисконнект.  Я опишу что мне удалось собрать позже в своём вопросе.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Обновил.

Comment: Скорее всего, у вас таймаут отлетает и сервер падает, а также возможно при отключении от сервера, соединение закрывается и сервер падает. попробуйте убрать ограничение работы скрипта и убрать прерывание скрипта после отключения клиента от сервера. `ignore_user_abort(true);`

Answer (score 4):

1) Собрать и конфигурировать самостоятельно php, nginx (apache) etc. - есть подозрение, что ваше окружение настроено не совсем так, или поднять виртуальную машину для этого (если ваша ОС - Windows) и там развернуть окружение. Возможно необходимого компонента для запуска react/event-loop в вашем стеке не обнаружено (предполагается наличие расширений в php)

2) Просматривать логи приложений, используемых в вашем стеке

3) Не использовать websocket c php

Comment: Как это сделать ? 2) Просматривать логи приложений, используемых в вашем стеке

Comment: Не могу сказать насчёт OpenServer - не знаю как там настроено, но в целом это текстовые файлы, читать текстовые файлы можно разными способами. На вопрос о том, где они лежат в вашем конкретном случае я ответить не могу.

Comment: `Возможно необходимого компонента для запуска react/event-loop в вашем стеке не обнаружено (предполагается наличие расширений в php)` Но, тестовый echo сервер отрабатывает на ура.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю тестовый это уже не ваш сервер.

Comment: Да, все верно, это `echo.websocket.org`.

Comment: Сл-но его конфигурация отлична от вашей. Вам необходимо настроить или сделать апгрейд своего локального сервера для работы с таким стеком, или взять nodejs и забыть про это :-)

Answer (score 4):

Есть подозрение, что сокет кем то еще используется.

Это обьясняет причину частичного коннекта.

Comment: Эх...Я перезагружал как сервер и веб-сервер тоже, но пока ничего не получается. Остальных серверов на websocket у меня нету. Но теория интересная.

Comment: А если порт попробовать сменить для теста?

Comment: @Я менял порты, сервера и клиента. И сегодня еще пробовал.

Answer (score 4):

Если проблем со связью с echo.websocket.org нет, а с вашим сервером есть - проблема в вашем сервере.
Раз используется готовый php-сервер, 99% - проблема не в скрипте.
Исходя из этого - проблема со связью клиент-сервер ... между клиентом и сервером.
Писать логи на любое событие и смотреть где происходит "разрыв".

В своё время тоже задавался вопросом "вебсокеты + php", но в итоге (как и предложили ранее) пришёл к node.js. Если вы в состоянии написать клиент на JS, то и с сервером у вас проблем не возникнет, зато появится много возможностей без лишних костылей.

Comment: Хм...Так для работы node.js нужно что бы он был установлен на хостинге, и был windows? Или я что-то путаю?

Comment: Установлен - да, windows - не обязательно (не желательно, на мой взгляд).  С хостинга лучше всего уже наконец переехать на VPS, всё таки 2016 год на дворе.