# WebSocket не принимает сообщения от клиентов PHP

Tags: php, javascript, websocket

Есть WebSocket, есть код какой принимает данные и отправляет, в общем все как положено. Все работает, но недолго, спустя немного времени (пару минут) и небольших манипуляций (обновления страницы и т.д.), сокет перестает принимать сообщения и я получаю из onclose такие данные:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На стороне сервера использую такую библиотеку:
https://github.com/pmill/php-chat

В интернете что-то очень мало информации по поводу этого и к сожалению очень слабо понимаю в какую сторону копать.

Вот мой js-код:

```
submit_msg.unbind('click').click(function () {
    var message = input_message.val().trim();

    if (message !== '') {
        sendChatMessage();
        input_message.val('');
    }

    input_message.focus();

    return false;
});

function connectToSocket() {
    conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:2222');
}

// ЭТО Я ПЫТАЛСЯ ВОЗОБНОВЛЯТЬ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ ЕСЛИ ОНО ЗАКРОЕТСЯ
function trackingStateWS() {
    interval_tracking_status_ws = setInterval(function() {
        if (conn.readyState === conn.CLOSED) {
            conn.close();
            connectToSocket();
        }
    }, 5000);
}

function connectToChat() {
    connectToSocket();

    trackingStateWS();

    conn.onopen = function () {
        var params = {
           // my params
        };
        conn.send(JSON.stringify(params));
    };

    conn.onmessage = function (e) {
        var data = JSON.parse(e.data),
            date = new Date(data.timestamp * 1000);

        // ОБРАБОТКА ПРИХОДЯЩИХ ДАННЫХ
    };

    conn.onclose = function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    };

    conn.onerror = function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    };

    return false;
}

function sendChatMessage() {
    var params = {
        // my params
    };
    conn.send(JSON.stringify(params));
    return false;
}
```

---

**ДОБАВЛЕНО**

Когда веб-сокет перестает отправлять сообщения от клиентов, они все равно могут подключатся к веб-сокету и у них отображается статус "в сети". Получается onopen работает всегда, а onmessage прекращает работать спустя пару минут.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74998/discussion-on-question-by-vlad-panchenko-websocket-----).

Answer (score 2):

## 1. Включите логи для PHP CLI

Нужно отредактировать `php.ini`, суть показана ниже

```
# запускаем консоль и вводим
php -a
# теперь мы в PHP CLI
echo php_ini_loaded_file();
echo ini_get('error_reporting');
echo ini_get('log_errors');
echo ini_get('error_log');
# Ctrl+C, теперь мы снова в bash
this_function_not_exists();
# Снова в командной строке
cat /var/log/cli_php_errors.log
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно убедиться, что правильно выставлены права на `/var/log/cli_php_errors.log`

## 2. Запускаем тестовый чат

Запускаем тестовый чат из консоли `php example/server.php`, ждем разрыва соединения, смотрим логи из пункта 1

```
cat /var/log/cli_php_errors.log
```

Пытаемся понять какие ошибки произошли в скрипте PHP. Вывод - запостить сюда.

Comment: Сделал все как вы сказали, вызвал ошибку, проверил что логи работают `[23-Mar-2018 16:37:34 Europe/Kiev] An Error occurred while handling another error ...`. Но разрыв соединения не показал каких-либо логов. Видимо потому что как такового разрыва соединения не было, пользователь может подключится к сокету, но не может отправить сообщение. Сколько пользуюсь Open Server, только сейчас увидел что он имеет свое окно для логов, там уже все настроено.

Comment: Open server = веб-сервер+база+PHP. Тут же мы запускаем php из консоли. Консольная версия имеет свой журнал логов, и не факт что она показывется OpSer. Вообще вот тут та же не решенная проблема. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512116/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-websocket